# How to pass Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on api projects in rails 4. I created all models by command `rails g model myModel`, some action in db/migrate has been created a file for migration db, which I do not use for this migrate.

If I run some controller, example `localhost:3000/report/data`

I found some error :

> "Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:
>
> ```
> bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development"
> ```

It means that, I've to run rails & migrate for every model that I created in my project.

how can I pass it for all models in rails 4? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats the general behaviour of Rails. When you create a model using `rails g model Name`, a migration file is created which when run, creates the associated table in database. Get your fundamentals cleared.

Comment: @Aakanksha ok... thanks for your answer... n sory for my bad fundamentals...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can skip migration creation using the command

```
rails g model User --skip-migration
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
rake db:reset
```

and then

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run

> bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="development"